# Is it possible to see tensorboard over ssh?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am running tensorflow code remotely on a ssh server.  (e.g., ssh -X account@server.address)

On the remote server, it says `You can navigate to http://0.0.0.0:6006`.

In this case, how can I check tensorboard? How can I navigate the address of a remote machine?
I tried to search, but there seems no useful information.

Comment: If you're using `-X`, you have X forwarding... do you have a web browser installed on the remote system you can run over X11?

Comment: Please be more precise on what you tried, the errors you encountered,...

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, I haven't thought to use `-X` and a remote web browser.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` is the wildcard address. Thus, you can use **any** address for the purpose unless the system's firewall is implementig something more restrictive.

That said, let's assume that it *is* implementing firewall-based restrictions (if it weren't, you could just access http://server.address:6006/ -- but so could anyone else). In that case:

```
ssh -L 16006:127.0.0.1:6006 account@server.address
```

...and then refer to http://127.0.0.1:16006/ in a local browser.

Comment: Connection failed ... XD

Comment: Two places that could be -- locally, because the LocalForward didn't get set up correctly, or remotely, because tensorboard isn't *really* accessible on 127.0.0.1:6006. You'll need to investigate which of those is actually the case yourself.

Comment: Do, also, note that the `ssh` instance opened with `-L` needs to stay open for the entire duration in which you're using this tunnel.

Comment: I'm not OP, I just clicked on the last link :p

Comment: Thanks! I tried but when I open "http://127.0.0.1:16006/" on a local web browser, the remote tensorboard says a multiple of 'channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused'. So I guess they are somehow connected, but tensorboard is not accessible on 127.0.0.1:6006.

Comment: I found that, as in your first suggestion, I could launch the remote server's firefox. I will try to use it for now. Thanks so much!