# Connecting to Tensorboard Logs on a Remote Server: The Connection was Reset

Tags: tensorboard, remote-server

When trying to connect to tensorboard logs on a remote server and entering the address  http://localhost:16006/ in chrome and firefox I get this message in the command line "channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused" multiple times and this message on the browser, "The Connection was Reset".
I ssh into the server like this: ssh -L 16006:127.0.0.1:6006 username@machine and then go one level up the log folder and write: tensorboard --logdir logs --port 16006

I tired:
tensorboard --logdir logs --port 16006 --bind-all
and also
tensorboard --logdir logs --host localhost,  also
tensorboard --logdir logs --host 127.0.0.1

None of the above has wroked. I tried running the line above from another environment which didn't help. I went to the office and tried connecting to the logs from the server machine directly and it worked.
It used to work before when accessing remotely. Do you know what the problem is? any hint would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same problem, but I think you should designate `--port 6006` since it looks like you are forwarding remote port 6006 to the local port 16006.

Even so, since 6006 is the default port, the other commands should have worked, but you would have to go to http://127.0.0.1:16006 on your local machine, rather than the link it provides.

Some more in depth explanations can be found here [how to run tensorboard on a remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987839/how-can-i-run-tensorboard-on-a-remote-server) and [how to see tensorboard over ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513333/is-it-possible-to-see-tensorboard-over-ssh)

Even following this advice though I am still getting a 'channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection failed' error